# aFreeRDP compile with Android Studio 2016

Tags: android, rdp, freerdp

Building aFreeRDP is simpler than before by Following link https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/blob/master/docs/README.android

I have Everything successfully: all lib files, import to A-S then build APK, install into Devices. But RDP session does not work properly. It keeping spinning dialog say connecting forever. Same thing happens with APKs from "./gradlew build"

Anyone can help?

Comment: Rebuild lib files and re-Configure screen resolution made it work, not sure why. Note: many Lib files now , (before only libfreerdp-android.so)

Comment: sxn, could please help me how you `rebuild lib files` and `re-configure` screen resolution? How many lib files in your `jniLibs -> armeabi` folder? I got 14 files. But there is no file named `libfreerdp-android.so`